# Roots and sums calculation

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $n_1, \ldots , n_{m+1}$ be natural numbers, possibly zeros. I want to introduce $$
\sum_{i=1}^m \sqrt{\frac{n_i}{n_{i+1}-n_i}}
$$
in terms of the s $S=\sum_{i=1}^{m+1}n_i$

Comment: You mean you want to *express* the top sum, of square roots of ratios, in terms of $S$? This is not possible if any denominator is zero, of course.

Comment: Why do you think there would be such a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $(n_1,n_2)=(1,4)$ and $(n_1,n_2)=(2,3)$ yield $S=5$ but $\sqrt{\dfrac{n_1}{n_2-n_1}}$ is $\dfrac1{\sqrt3}$ in one case and $\sqrt2$ in the other case. Hence $S$ does not determine the sum you are interested in, even the sequence $(n_i)$ is suitable (that is, either nonnegative and increasing, or nonpositive and decreasing).

Comment: Thank you, what about $$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\sqrt{\frac{n_i}{n_{i+1}}}$$ it means that this sjm is also impossible to bound in terms of S?